# jmeter .jtl log file to csv conversion

Tags: java, regex, csv, jmeter

I tried to convert the jmeter .jtl file to csv file.
 Each line of jtl file contains the variables separated by commas as in normal csv file.
For example: a,b,c,d,e,f
 However, in some of the lines there are multiple delimiter like comma(,) and comma inside quotation(",").
For example : a,b,"c,d",e,f
I could parse the comma separated value easily by reading the jtl file . But when I encounter comma inside quotation delimiter, by code fails to generate the useful result.
I tried to use java multi split , but still the problem persists.

My java code is as follows :

```
try{
 BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File("D:/apache-jmeter-2.11/apache-jmeter-2.11/bin/")))));
while((line = reader.readLine()) !=null){   
    String[] datas = line.split("[,\",\"]");
     p.println(datas[0] + "," + datas[5] + "," + datas[2] + "," + datas[1] + "," + datas[3] + "," + datas[8] + "," + datas[9]); 
}
```

I have used split to split using (,)and (","). How shoud i rewrite the code so that the problem could be solved.

Comment: any feedback on my answer ?

Answer (score 1):

Use [uniVocity-parsers](http://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial) to read this:

```
CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings(); //many options to configure the format and the parser here. Check the tutorial
CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(settings);
List<String[]> allRows = parser.parseAll(
    new FileReader(new File("D:/apache-jmeter-2.11/apache-jmeter-2.11/bin/")));
```

Disclosure: I am the author of this library. It's open-source and free (Apache V2.0 license).

Answer (score 0):

Use this library which will handle this for you:

- https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/user-guide.html

Read javadoc to understand how to specify format:

- https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/archives/1.1/apidocs/index.html

Answer (score 0):

For me what you are looking for is an existing CSV processing library that you can make use of. I use OpenCSV with success to process JMeter output, but this is obviously just one of many possible options.

Answer (score 0):

[JTL files](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) can take the form of two different formats, *CSV* or *XML*.  The vast majority of use cases utilize the CSV format, which you are describing.

To convert a JTL file to a CSV file is as simple as changing the file extension to `*.csv`.  Editing and analysis of JTL files can therefore be performed using an ordinary spreadsheet application (*e.g.*, Excel) as described in [this article](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2022/03/compare-load-tests-results-using-csv-data/).

If you want to programmatically analyze a JTL file and treat it as a CSV file, this can be accomplished with any CSV processing library.  There are several examples given in other answers to this question.  One additional method using C#/.Net would be referencing the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace and employing the `TextFieldParser`:

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;
...
using (var textFieldParser = new TextFieldParser(path)
{
    TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited 
})
{
    textFieldParser.SetDelimiters(",");
    while (!textFieldParser.EndOfData) 
    {
        foreach (string field in parser.ReadFields())
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

More detailed information about usage of the `TextFieldParser` can be found on the [official Microsoft documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser?view=net-7.0).